# recursive sub-sequences of sequence , one is increasing and one is decreasing to same limit -> the sequence converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $b_1=\:0$, $b_{n+1}\:=\:\frac{1}{1+b_n}$.
I need to show that $\left(b_n\right)_{n\:=1}^{\infty }$ converge.

I thought about dived $b_n$ to 2 sub_sequence : $b_{2n}$, $b_{2n+1}$. (i thought about it  because intuition: it is very clear if you start to put values to n, you see that $b_{2n-1}$ increasing and $b_{2n}\:$ decreasing)

So, its true to say that ? :
 $b_{2n}\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}1 & n=1 \\b_{2\left(n+1\right)}\:=\:\frac{1}{1+b_{2n}} & \forall n\end{pmatrix}$, $b_{2n-1}\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}0 & n=1 \\b_{2\left(n+1\right)-1}\:=\:\frac{1}{1+b_{2n-1}} & \forall n\end{pmatrix}$
If its correct, how can i prove that these two are bounded? tnx for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n$ be the $n^{th}$ fibonacci number.

Then, if $b_n = \dfrac{f_{n-1}}{f_{n}}$, we get $b_{n+1} = \dfrac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}}$

Thus $b_n$ are the convergents of the continued fraction for $\varphi$, the golden ratio and your observations about alternate terms increasing/decreasing are true.

To answer the question in your title, yes, if $b_{2n} \to L$ and $b_{2n+1} \to L$ then $b_n \to L$, does not have to be increasing/decreasing etc, those two just need to be converging.